# Удалить окончание строки вместе с датой

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка xxxxxxxxx 10.12.2012 xxxxxx.

Необходимо удалить все, начиная с даты

```
 preg_replace("/([0-2]\d|3[01])\.(0\d|1[012])\.(\d{1,4})$/", " ",$pass_agensy);
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Соррь. Не понял, что американский формат.
У вас просто группировка неправильная

```
(?:[0-2]\d)|(?:3[01])\.(?:0\d)|(?:1[012])\.(\d{1,4})
```

Comment: в таком случае остается "xxxxxxxxx ..12 xx"

Comment: @knes не длинновата регулярочка?)

---------------

`/\d+.+(.*)/`

Comment: Нет, не длинновата. Ваша не учитывает то, что через точку может написана быть не только дата. :)

Comment: Alangel, используйте опережающую проверку. В качестве аргумента - вот эту самую регулярку в скобках.

    .*(?=(?:[0-2]\d)|(?:3[01])\.(?:0\d)|(?:1[012])\.(\d{1,4}))

Или как-то так.

Comment: preg_replace("!(?=([0-2]\d|3[01])\.(0\d|1[012])\.(\d{1,4})).+!is", "", $pass_agensy);

получилось как то так..

Answer (score 2):

А если без регулярного выражения? Можно взять часть Вашей строки до первого пробела:

```
<?php 
    $st = 'xxxxxxxxx 10.12.2012 xxxxxx';            
    $st = substr($st, 0, strpos($st, ' ')); // $st = 'xxxxxxxxx'
?>
```

Comment: там не обязательно одно слово, может быть и несколько

Comment: ну так может найти сначала позицию вхождения числа а потом как в ответе

Comment: а допустим в строке встречаются числа, помимо нашей даты?

Comment: ну а дата имеет формат стабильный?можно через регуляр найти дату.

Comment: дата либо 10.12.2012 либо 10.12.12